# Remove sudo command usage

Tags: macos, sudo

I am tehcnically administrator on my mac mini, on the initial installion of Ionic dependency I am using sudo command. Now of file associated with this framework have permission issue. This shouldn't be problem as I am administrator

I am kindly asking you guys, has anyone know how to remove this sudo and give permission to all activity on my mac?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ionic following the directions from the two pages below, then you shouldn't need to use `sudo` after the installation:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html

Or did I misunderstand your question?